# ¿Como puedo modificar este programa de manera que solo utilice enteros para calcular el interés compuesto?

Tags: c

Según la pista que me dieron en el ejercicio, tengo que tratar todas las cantidades monetarias como numeros enteros centavos. Luego romper el resultado en su parte entera y de centavos mediante el uso de las operaciones de división y de residuo, respectivamente. E insertar un punto.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
double monto; /* monto del depósito */
double principal = 1000.0; /* monto principal */
double tasa = .05; /* interés compuesto anual */
int anio; /* contador de años */

printf( “%4s%21s\n”, “Anio”, “Monto del deposito” );

/* calcula el monto del depósito para cada uno de los diez años */
for ( anio = 1; anio <= 10; anio++ ) {

/* calcula el nuevo monto para el año especificado */
monto = principal * pow( 1.0 + tasa, anio );

printf( “%4d%21.2f\n”, anio, monto );
} 

return 0; 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tienes que almacenar las unidades como enteros centavos, el primer paso sería multiplicar las cantidades por 100:

```
int principal = 100000;  // 1000 * 100
double tasa = .05;       // no es cantidad monetaria, no cambia
```

Como todas las variables trabajan con las mismas unidades, puedes hacer operaciones entre ellas sin miedo.

Luego, para imprimir los valores, tendrás que separar estas cantidades para diferenciar la parte entera de la decimal.

La parte entera se calcula dividiendo la cantidad por cien, mientras que la parte decimal se calcula con el módulo:

```
int parte_entera  = cantidad / 100;
int parte_decimal = cantidad % 100;
```

Por ejemplo:

```
printf("%d.%02d", monto/100, monto%100);
```